# Adding together separate values from case expression

Tags: sql-server

This query is bringing up separate Total amounts due to the case statement. Is there an easy way to add them together to show up as one total value?

```
SELECT  
    ih.customer_id AS [Customer ID],
    customer.customer_name AS [Customer],
    COUNT(ih.invoice_no) AS [Orders],
    CASE 
        WHEN il.unit_of_measure = 'IN' 
            THEN (SUM((il.qty_shipped*12) * il.unit_price)) 
            ELSE SUM(il.qty_shipped * il.unit_price) 
    END AS [Total]
FROM
    invoice_hdr ih
INNER JOIN 
    invoice_line il ON ih.invoice_no = il.invoice_no
INNER JOIN 
    customer ON customer.customer_id = ih.customer_id
GROUP BY 
    ih.customer_id, customer.customer_name, il.unit_of_measure
ORDER BY 
    ih.customer_id
```

Comment: Aaron when I take it out of the group by I get "Column 'invoice_line.unit_of_measure' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: You need to move your *case expression* inside of the aggregation.

Comment: Stu when I put SUM() around the case I get an error because of the SUM()'s I already use in the case statement. Error - Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @jrdev12345 See the syntax I posted as an answer below

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am still very new to SQL and couldn't find a similar question searching on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `unit_of_measure` column from your `group by` you can refer to it *within* the sum, can you try the following:

```
 Sum(il.qty_shipped * il.unit_price * case when il.unit_of_measure = 'IN' then 12 else 1 end) end as Total
```